# Showing gal$(\mathbb{Q}(u): \mathbb{Q}) $ is isomorphic to a particular cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

I am preparing for an exam and this problem was in the recommended review questions from the textbook, but I am having trouble with it.

> Let $u = e^{\pi i/q}$, where $q$ is an odd prime. Show that
>   gal($(\mathbb{Q}(u): \mathbb{Q}) \simeq C_{q-1}$ (the cyclic group of
>   order $q-1$).
>
> Hint: show that $\mathbb{Q}(u^2) = \mathbb{Q}(u)$.

I think I can figure out how to prove the statement (based on an example we have previously seen) once I have shown the hint. However, I am not sure how to proceed with that part.

Comment: Hint:  what is $\left(u^2\right)^{\frac {q+1}2}$?

Comment: @lulu Sorry if I’m being obtuse, I’m not following where to go from that. That gives $u^{q+1}$?

Comment: Ok...but of course $u^{q+1}=u^q\times u$.  What is $u^q$?

Comment: Since $\mathbb{Q}(u^2) \subset \mathbb{Q}(u)$, it suffices to prove $u \in \mathbb{Q}(u^2)$. Let $v = u^2$. Then $v^{(2q+1)/2} = u^{2q+1} = u$ since $u^{2q} = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

This follows from the group theory result that $Aut(C_p)=C_{p-1}$ for $p$ prime, which makes it clear that the Galois group contains a $C_{p-1}$ subgroup, combined with the fact that adjoining one of the roots already gives the splitting field (since the others are its powers), so the Galois group has order $p-1$ so it must equal $C_{p-1}$.