# Prove $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(e^{\pi i/q}):\mathbb{Q}) \cong C_{q-1}$ for odd prime q.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $u=e^{\pi i/q}$, where $q$ is an odd prime number. I want to  Show that $\operatorname{Gal}l(\mathbb{Q}(u):\mathbb{Q})\simeq C_{q-1}$

My thought is to find the polynomial $x^q+1$ and find a minimal polynomial for $u$ so that I can find its other roots, but I'm unsure of how to do this.

Any ideas?

Comment: There are a lot of proofs that the cyclotomic polynomials are irreducible, they are non-trivial. Do you know for $p \nmid n$ there is a surjective morphism $\Bbb{Z}[\zeta_n]\to \Bbb{Z}[\zeta_n]/(p) \to \Bbb{F}_{p^{r_p}}$ where $r_p$ is the order of $p \bmod n$, sending $\zeta_n$ to a primitive $n$-th root of unity $\omega_{n,p} \in \Bbb{F}_{p^{r_p}}$ ? Let $\Phi_n \in \Bbb{Z}[x]$ the minimal polynomial of $\zeta_n$, then $\Phi_n(\omega_{n,p}) = 0\bmod p$ implies $\Phi_n(\omega_{n,p}^p) =\Phi_n(\omega_{n,p})^p = 0\bmod p$ which in return implies $\Phi_n(\zeta_n^p)= 0$.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2745346/showing-gal-mathbbqu-mathbbq-is-isomorphic-to-a-particular-cyclic-g?rq=1).

Comment: Chiming in with Dietrich. Given that $q$ is prime, the minimal polynomial is $(x^q-1)/(x-1)$ that you can show irreducible using Eisenstein.